# Setfocus to Textbox in adempiere

Tags: adempiere

I have tired set focus to text box in adempiere. its not working for me. Can you please tel me how to achieve this?

How to set the cursor focus to a textbox in adempiere.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this problem in Form, the default java statements can be used to set the cursor focus. That is

```
myComponent.grabFocus();
myComponent.requestFocus();//or inWindow
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please briefly explain what was the exact problem? Do you need callout ?

we need to modify the core classes of Framework for Field focus change purpose.

Comment: yes, I want to focus the text field after hit the button. what is the classes of framework for field focus?